# Box plot using JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart, boxplot

First off, I am new to Java and to Stackoverflow. So I hope I can supply enough clarity in my question.

My goal is to create a box plot using jfreechart to keep track of measurement values from every day use. I want to do this by storing minimal amount of data ie. by storing statists of mean, standard deviation, median, 1Q,3Q, min and maximum. This should then be visualized by a box plot for each day measured.

I have looked at the box plot demo here
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartBoxAndWhiskerDemo.htm

In this demo they create the dataset and add all the values to the dataset, then adds it to the plot. The dataset itself contains methods to return the mean, median etc. of the dataset to be able to create the plot. See the code below for a snip from the demo in the link above.

```
    DefaultBoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultBoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset();
    //some type of algorithm to add values to the dataset
    dataset.add(//values, series and type here);
    // Return the finished dataset
    CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis("Type");
    NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis("Value");
    yAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
    BoxAndWhiskerRenderer renderer = new BoxAndWhiskerRenderer();
    renderer.setFillBox(false);
    renderer.setToolTipGenerator(new BoxAndWhiskerToolTipGenerator());
    CategoryPlot plot = new CategoryPlot(dataset, xAxis, yAxis,
            renderer);

    JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("Box-and-Whisker Demo",
            new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 14), plot, true);
```

So my question is, how should I do to just add the median, Q1,Q3, mean, minimum and maximum values to create the box plot? Because in the demo above they base the plot of a complete sample set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own dataset class and use it to create the chart.

Create your own implementation of [BoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/statistics/BoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset.html) and use it in place of `DefaultBoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset`.

Comment: Okey, thanks for the answer, I will +1 as soon as I get 15 rep, do you mean that I should rewrite the whole class or subclass it and then override the methods used?

Comment: Your class can be something like: MyDataSet extends AbstractDataset implements BoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset. Hopefully you will not need to rewrite many methods.